# SSIS Upgrade Wizard gone in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade, ssis-2008, ssis-2017

My company has started a project of upgrading from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2017. My team is responsible for migrating about 70 SSIS project, some SSRS and SSAS.

I know that SSIS development in Visual Studio 2017 is quite new, since the SQL Server Data Tools just got into GA release. But I have managed to install it on my computer, develop with SSIS designer and also open old SSIS projects, and then the SSIS Upgrade Wizard shows.

BUT, somehow my SSIS Upgrade Wizard does not pop up anymore. It just gives error

> project type .dtproj is not recognized

I'm still able to create new SSIS projects, but I'm depenging on the posibility to migrate/upgrade my old projects.

Is there any extensions/dependencies I miss, or is there any application that is "blocking" this feature?

I have several Visual Studio versions installed and the list in "Add or remove programs" is full of different Visual Studio and .NET components in different versions. It is impossible to know what to delete etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many Visual Studio version installed you can open the Visual Studio 2017 from the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
```

Then try to open the project.

If it fails, then try creating a new SSIS 2017 project, add the packages *(.dtsx)* files manually, then right click on `Packages` in the Solution Explorer and Click on Upgrade All

**Additional Information**

- [Upgrade Integration Services Packages Using the SSIS Package Upgrade Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard)

Comment: Thanks, this sound like a good workaround, but I would really like the Upgrade Wizard up and going again. I will test a few things today (also open from this folder), but if this does not work I will try creating new project and copy .dtsx files and upgrade them.

Comment: Have you tried to open visual studio 2017 and open the project. *(not double click on the solution file)*